# About Multiplicity in Model first: Does Many mean '0..*' or '1..*'?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-model-first, multiplicity

I'm new to database and Entity Framwork, when I use Model first to build a database, there are three choices, so here Many means 0..* or 1..* ? If a relationship is one to many, here Many is kind of 0..* , does it mean a foreign key here is nullable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

0..* means 0 to many so there doesn't need to be an entry in the foreign table that matches.

1..* means 1 to many so there must be an entry in the foreign table.

Comment: So Many means  0..* or 1..* ?

Comment: Well, my question is if 'Many' can be 0 or at least one in the model first entity framework, but now I think the default setting means at least one and if I want 0 I need to go to the database and specify the fk can bu null.